# Broken DAG : Bad response from application: 429

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I started getting this error when I started to develop the `awin_integration.py` dag.

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/media/awin_integration.py] Bad response from application: 429 / {'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '0', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '105', 'Date': 'Sun, 17 Jan 2021 19:38:09 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'} / {"error":"request.limit.exceeded","description":"Requests limit '20' times per '1' minutes' is exceeded"}
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: It seems this has nothing to do with airflow, but with an underlying API called from the DAG that exceeds the limits of calls per minute. But what I don't understand, is why it breaks the DAG, instead of simply failing the task with an exception.

Comment: Make sure your DAG not executed while its parsed by the DagBag by implementing logic in Operators or Sensors. That way you'll have an error when the Task Instance fails instead of when the DAG is added to your DagBag.

Comment: @vdolez, could you display an example of this logic?

Comment: You can have a look at the Jdbc example from Github : https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/jdbc
You need to see that a DAG definition is just a configuration file, which then call the operators and the underlying logic of the hook.
DAG files are interpreted when they are read by the DagBag : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#it-s-a-dag-definition-file